# Can any value be url encoded using IS0-8859-1?

Tags: http, character-encoding, webserver

I thought a server expected urls to be encoded as UTF-8 so I always encoded my urls as UTF-8, however it turns out it expects them to be encoded as IS0-8859-1.

Can any value be url encoded using IS0-8859-1 even if includes chinese, arabic and other non latin chars because it would be much simpler to fix the client then the server.

**Update from Answer**

So I was a bit confused if my query value is 'Björk' and I put it into IE Explorer I got the expected results, if I put the same value into Firefox I get incorrect results. My theoreom was that IE was uriencoding to iso8859 and my server expected to receive as iso8859 so worked, but firefox was uriencoding as utf8 and as  my server always expect iso8859 it decodes incorrectly and give wrong results,

In fact I'm sure this is right because I get the correct results if I uriencode as iso8859 in my client code and bad results if i urlencode in UTF8. If I dont uriencode at all then server fails to understand the query at all, so you do have to uri encode.

Because I was searching for an ö I thought that meant anything could be encoded as ISO88591. I realize its only one byte (256 chars) but I thought uriencoding conveted chars into multiple bytes before encoding, but now realized that ö is actually in IS0-8859 as char 214.

So I guess the only solution is have the server expect UTF8 and have the client send UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) There is no requirement to use any specific encoding in URIs. But yes, UTF-8 is the best choice. Just don't rely on everybody doing it.

b) No, ISO-8859-1 can only represent 256 different characters.